# crawler update data to an array, yield inside a loop

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to continuous crawl and update an array value using loop because I need to click some button to get next value on array.
However it seem yield inside loop works as parallel thread and the item was yield many time.
What I want is go through the loop, update data and yield item only one time.
example:
current output:

```
{'field1': 'data1',
 'filed2' : 'data2',
 'field3' : ['data31']}

{'field1': 'data1',
 'filed2' : 'data2',
 'field3' : ['data32']}

{'field1': 'data1',
 'filed2' : 'data2',
 'field3' : ['data33']}
```

expected:

```
{'field1': 'data1',
 'filed2' : 'data2',
 'field3' : ['data31', 'data32', 'data3']}
```

Here is my code

```
def parse_individual_listings(self, response):
     ...
     data = {}
     data[field1] = 'data1'
     data[field1] = 'data2'
     ...
     for i in range(3):
         yield scrapy.Request(
                urlparse.urljoin(response.url, link['href']), #different link
                callback=self.parse_individual_tabs,
                meta={'data': data, 'n':i};
         )
def parse_individual_tabs(self, response):
     data = response.meta['data']
     i = response.meta['i']
     ...
     # keep populating `data`
     data[field3][i] = "data3[i]"  #this value change when I click a button to update
     yield data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `inline_requests` library (https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-inline-requests/). It let's you to make requests inside the same function. It is useful to collect data to one object instead of yielding different. Check this example with some pseudocode:

```
from inline_requests import inline_requests
from scrapy import Selector

@inline_requests
def parse_individual_listings(self, response):
    ...
    data = {}
    data[field1] = 'data1'
    data[field1] = 'data2'
     ...
    for i in range(3):
        extra_req = yield scrapy.Request(
            response.urljoin(link['href']), #different link
        )
        # apply your logics here, say extract some data
        sel = Selector(text=extra_req.text)
        data['field3'].append(sel.css('some css selector').get())
    yield data
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow multi thread and unsynchronized idea, I end up using mutex lock in parse_individual_tabs and it seems work fine.

```
from threading import Lock
...
mutex = Lock()
count = 0
...
def parse_individual_tabs(self, response):
 self.mutex.acquire(1)
 try:
    count += 1
    data = response.meta['data']
    i = response.meta['i']
    ...
    # keep populating `data`
    data[field3][i] = "data3[i]"  #this value change when I click a button to update
 finally:
        self.mutex.release()
 if (count == 3):   #check if this is callback of last yield Request
     yield data
 else:
     return
```